# why doesnt my onclick override an earlier executed js function?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Why doesnt my onclick override an earlier executed js function? The function gets triggered from within an echo in php. The function gets executed and changes an image and its width and height. Later if i click on my button i want the image to change again, however only the image changes and not the width and height.

```
<script>
     function helmfunc() {            
                document.getElementById("helmplace").src = "helmimg/s_helmet.png";  //executes                               
    document.getElementById("helmplace").style.width = "22px"; //executes
    document.getElementById("helmplace").style.height = "31px"; //executes                    
                }
</script>
<img id="helmplace" name="showh" src="redx3.png" width="25" height="30" />
<span onclick="showh.src = x_helm.src; showh.width = x_helm.width; showh.height = x_helm.height; helm.value = 'x helm'">
                <il>
                    <img id="xhelmid" name="x_helm" src="helmimg/x_helmet.png" width="22" height="31" />x Helm
                </il>
            </span>
```

Inside some php: (furthest down in the body)

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> slayerhelmfunc(); </script>';
```

Comment: Use an Event Listener instead of an onclick.

Comment: yup works now, fell kinda stupid that ive been stuck on this for so long :P

Comment: @ThomasJuranek Since it seems to have worked, can you change your comment to an answer so it can be upvoted and accepted?

Comment: I did so, and as the site suggests I should probably not answer questions in the comments. :P +techturtle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using an onclick, the generally accepted way to run code on a click is using event listeners. Here is an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <input type="number" id="inputInteger" />
 <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" text="Submit" />
    
    <p id="result"></p>

 <script type = "text/javascript">
        // Event Listener that Runs "Compute()" on a Click
        document.getElementById("btnSubmit").addEventListener("click", compute);

        // Gets Input Value and Displays it in a <p>
        function compute() {
            var day = document.getElementById("inputInteger").value;
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = day;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```